# NSPredicate filter by first letter that is contained in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate

I have an array of strings:

```
@[@"ballot", @"1-time", @"32marks", @"zoo"];
```

I need a predicate that finds all the strings that start with a number. So the filtered array should be:

```
@[@"1-time", @"32marks"]
```

Here's what I'm trying so far:

```
data = @[@"ballot", @"1-time", @"32marks", @"zoo"];
NSArray *numbers = @[@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5",@"6", @"7"];
NSPredicate *firstPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K IN %@", numbers];
NSPredicate *secondPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH"];

NSCompoundPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                                      @[firstPredicate, secondPredicate]];

data = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

It crashes with:

```
-[__NSArrayI rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15fc99a0
```

I don't think I need a compound predicate but I can't figure out how to format 'numbers' into the predicate string so that it chooses any number string in 'numbers'. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pass a simple regex to your predicate to match any strings that begin with a number. Something like:

```
NSArray *data = @[@"ballot", @"1-time", @"32marks", @"zoo"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"^\\d.+"];
// Or ^\\d(.+)? if you want to match single-digit numbers also

data = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"%@", data); // Outputs: ("1-time", 32marks)
```